# Windows batch file to import LAN or Wireless profile regardless interface name

Tags: windows, networking, batch-file

How do I ignore interface name when importing network profile?

Below batch files only work if the endpoint have the same interface name (Windows interface names usually are: Local Area Connection, Wireless Network Connection, Ethernet, Wi-Fi) as defined in below 2 batch files. The existing batch files that I have are as below:

**for LAN:**

```
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query "dot3svc" ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
  if /I "%%H" NEQ "RUNNING" (
   sc start dot3svc
  )
)
   sc config dot3svc start= auto
   netsh lan add profile filename=".\Local Area Connection.xml"
```

**for WLAN**

```
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query "WlanSvc" ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
  if /I "%%H" NEQ "RUNNING" (
   sc start WlanSvc
  )
)
   sc config WlanSvc start= auto
   netsh wlan add profile filename=".\Wireless Network Connection-mywifiname.xml"
```

Comment: I'm dealing with something similar at work. Using PowerShell to get the list of interface names and running an if-else loop to run the add profile command